# what is the purpose of the magic number in linux reboots?

Tags: linux, reboot

On the Wikipedia page for Linus Torvalds, it states that:

'The Linux kernel's reboot system call accepts their dates of birth (written in hexadecimal) as magic values'.

And documentation for the Linux reboot function shows that it needs two magic numbers, 'magic' and 'magic2' too reboot.

What is the purpose of these magic numbers? Why can't the function operate without them?

Thanks

Answer (score 14):

A quick google of your question yields the answer;

http://www.eeggs.com/items/44291.html

In order to prevent the reboot() system call being
called inadvertently, you must pass it a pair of magic values in the first two parameters. The first magic value is 0xfee1dead. The second magic value
is one of:

```
$ grep LINUX_REBOOT_MAGIC include/linux/*.h
include/linux/reboot.h:#define LINUX_REBOOT_MAGIC1 0xfee1dead
include/linux/reboot.h:#define LINUX_REBOOT_MAGIC2 672274793
include/linux/reboot.h:#define LINUX_REBOOT_MAGIC2A 85072278
include/linux/reboot.h:#define LINUX_REBOOT_MAGIC2B 369367448
include/linux/reboot.h:#define LINUX_REBOOT_MAGIC2C 537993216
```

These are dates of significance to Linus; hint
you can use perl to convert them into dates:

```
$ perl -e 'print localtime(672274793). "\n";'
```

Sun Apr 21 18:59:53 1991

This is the date that Linus first started writing Linux. The significance of other dates is left as an exercise for the reader ;-)

Comment: _"This is the date that Linus first started writing Linux."_ Oh really?? No one in their right mind could take that seriously! Do you recall any single time (to a second) when you started writing any one of the programs you have written? I doubt that. Your programs are probably not as significant as Linux, but Linus did not initially set out to write an OS kernel; at the beginning it was not a particularly substantial project, and so it is unlikely he would have noted the exact time (with a second precision) when he "started writing Linux". (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) The meaning of these numbers is more prosaic. When represented in hexadecimal numeral system, they equal `28121969`, `05121996`, `16041998` and `20112000` respectively; the first of which is the date of birth of Linus Torvalds himself, and the latter three are the dates of birth of his daughters Patricia, Daniela and Celeste respectively.